# How to get count in Django for a model two foreign keys away

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have three modles in my Django app as follows:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(length=50)

class Area(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    area_name = models.CharField(length=50)

class Person(models.Model):
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    person_name = models.CharField(length=50)
```

I require cities in order of their population (i.e. Person basis). How is it possible with Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `annotate` to count population.

```
City.objects.annotate(population=Count("area_set___person_set")).order_by("population")
```

Comment: Hello Reza, thanks for the answer. This did not work directly, but pointed towards right direction. This solution has worked for me:
`City.objects.annotate(population=Count('area__person')).order_by('-population')`

Comment: Do you have `related_name` in ForeignKey ?

Comment: No that is not the case. If you look at the documentation, the `_set` is not used in the example. I just didn't know if it could work for two foreign keys away.